# Boundary of compact set

Tags: general-topology

My question is:

Is the boundary, $\partial K=\overline{K}\setminus \operatorname{int}(K)$, of any subset $K$ of any topological space $X$ necessarily compact?

Comment: In a Hausdorff or a regular space it is not possible because the closure of a compact set is compact in such a space and $\partial K$ is a closed subset of $\overline K$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Take $A$ to be any infinite set and $x$ to be anything not in $A$. Now consider the space $X = A \cup \{x\}$ with the topology where a set is open iff it's empty or it contains $x$. Thus $A$ has the discrete topology as a subspace of $X$ and $\{x\}$ is compact (as it's finite). But $\overline{\{x\}} = X$ and $\{x\}^\circ = \{x\}$, so $\partial \{x\} = A$ which—being an infinite discrete space—is not compact.

Comment: Thank you, I want improve my question, it's true in euclidean space??

Comment: @Soma: It is true whenever $∂K ⊆ K$ since then it's a closed subspace of compact space. So it holds if compact subset of $X$ must be closed. This holds for any $X$ Hausdorff and so in euclidean space.

Comment: Isn't $x$ closed in the topology of the excluded point? Maybe you mean the topoology of the included point. In that case the closure of $\{x\}$ would be all $X$, and the interior would be $\{x\}$, so the boundary would be $A$.

Comment: @StefanH. Duly noted.

Comment: No, you still have to change the topology. The open sets should be the sets containing $x.$